# CentOS installer hangs through IPMI

Tags: centos, centos7, installation, remote, ipmi

I am trying to install CentOS remotely in a supermicro server through the Java IPMI applet and the installer hangs either on "starting network manager", or "starting pre-anaconda logging service".

I have tried `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1708` and `CentOS-7-x86_64-NetInstall-1708`, I have tried normal install, check disk and install, and basic install, but I am not able to get through to the installer with any of the options or ISOs.

The initial welcome screen where I can choose the install option appears, but not the following screen. I choose the install option, I get the console screen where startup begins, showing [OK] at the beginning of the lines and the several startup messages, but it either hangs at one of the above options, or it simply stalls with a black screen and does not follow through to the installer.

This server had an earlier version of CentOS installed with no issues that I can recall, I was able to boot DBAN iso beforehand to clean the server up, and I am out of clues as to what I am missing here. Is there a way I can ditch Anaconda, and maybe go with a text installer to see if the problem goes away, or anything else I should be trying?

Here is a screenshot of the current status:
[image: CentOS installer hanging]

Thank you.

Comment: Unlike your problem, but related, I was unable to install Centos 7 some days ago with similar hair splitting issues. What finally worked was I removed any network cable connected to the server and the installation completed like a breeze. Try disconnecting anything from the server line Network cable, USB etc etc

Comment: @termcap unfortunately this is a remote installation, I am not able to remove the network card.

Comment: You connect ISO image trough Virtual CD or it's installation from PXE?

Comment: @AlexanderTolkachev through virtual storage iso, from the KVM applet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find the answer but I found a solution.

I was able to install CentOS using an older version of the installer, that I had previously installed on this server: `CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1511`